# Get Json Key value from List[Row] with Scala

Tags: scala, list, row

Let's say that I have a List[Row] such as `{"name":"abc,"salary","somenumber","id":"1"},{"name":"xyz","salary":"some_number_2","id":"2"}`

How do I get the JSON key value pair with scala. Let's assume that I want to get the value of the key "salary". IS the below one right ?

```
val rows = List[Row] //Assuming that rows has the list of rows

for(row <- rows){
   row.get(0).+("salary")
}
```

Comment: What frameworks are you using? Is `Row` from Spark SQL or is it your own class? Are you using some specific Json library?

Comment: yeah it's the Row from Spark SQL @Simon. And I am not using any JSON library as of now. Let's assume that the data is from kafka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `List[Row]` I assume that you've had a `DataFrame` and you did `collectAsList`. If you `collect`/`collectAsList` that means that you

1. Can no longer use that Spark SQL operations
2. Can not run your calculations in parallel on the nodes in your cluster. At this point everything is executed in your **driver**.

I would recommend keeping it as a DataFrame and then doing:

```
val salaries = df.select("salary")
```

Then you can do further calculations on the salaries, `show` them or `collect` or persist them somewhere.

If you choose to use `DataSet` (which is like a typed `DataFrame`) then you could do

```
val salaries = dataSet.map(_.salary)
```

Comment: Thank you @simon. I didn't do collectAsList. What if i dont want to use a dataframe and I want to do normal operations as the other answer

Comment: Then it's probably easier to just use a plain Kafka consumer and a Json library to process your messages, because using Spark that way will probably not give you any benefits. It will both be harder to code and code be less performant

Answer (score 0):

Using Spray Json:

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

object sprayApp extends App {
  val list = List("""{"name":"abc","salary":"somenumber","id":"1"}""", """{"name":"xyz","salary":"some_number_2","id":"2"}""")
  val jsonAst = list.map(_.parseJson)
  for(l <- jsonAst) {
    println(l.asJsObject.getFields("salary")(0))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @EmiCareOfCell44 . But the same does not go with List[Row] where Row is of Spark SQL type

Comment: Yes, I saw your comment indicating that Row was form Spark SQL after

Comment: yeah. So is there any other way to go about it ?